# app checkDebugAarMetadata error when using android video view

Tags: android, kotlin

I was developing a local video player with Android (kotlin) and with a video view tag.
and I found this error. **how to resolve this?  Is this a problem with the video or code?**

My kotlin file is at attached at the bottom.

[image: image of aap checkDebugAarMetaData Error]

```
       val videoView = findViewById<VideoView>(binding.testView.id)

    val mediaController = MediaController(this)
    mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView)

    val uri:Uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://"+packageName+"/raw/a")

    videoView.setMediaController(mediaController)
    videoView.setVideoURI(uri)
    videoView.requestFocus()
    videoView.start()
```